# Creating a Table of Context from a list of dicts using Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Say that I have the following dict list:

```
fruits = [
    {"Name": "Apple", "id": 1, "url": "/apple", "Desc": "Red or green skin with white flesh."},
    {"Name": "Pear", "id": 2, "url": "/pear", "Desc": "Green fruit with white flesh."},
    {"Name": "Coconut", "id": 3, "url": "/coco", "Desc": "Brown hairy shell with with flesh."}
]
```

and it's passed to the context of a Django template via a view. How would I go about building a Table of Context that looks something Like this?

---

**A**
[Apple](/apple)
Red or green skin with white flesh.


**C**
[Coconut](/coco)
Brown hairy shell with with flesh.


**P**
[Pear](/pear)
Green fruit with white flesh..

---

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
    <B>{{ fruit.Name|first_letter_upper }}</B><BR>
    <A HREF="{{ fruit.url }}">{{ fruit.Name }}</A><BR>
    {{ fruit.Desc }}<BR>
    {% if not forloop.last %}<BR>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But then I would have to implement the custom filter "first_letter_upper". Not a big deal, but I'm just wondering if there's a simpler way to do that without having to use custom filters?

Comment: do not make processing on client side - just add a new key and pass the updated data to django. a quick way -  `fruits = [i.get('First', i['Name'][0].upper()) for  i in fruits]`

Comment: I thought the templates were rendered at the server side and then the results were passed to the client. Isn't that the case?

Comment: @CristianVarela The template engine is on your server, not on the client side.

Comment: Thanks @MosesKoledoye, that's what I thought. The suggestion above then wouldn't have any performance improvement benefit - but thanks anyway.

Comment: @CristianVarela Processing in plain Python is faster than on the template side.

Comment: I see, thanks both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first letter uppercase by combining [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) and [`upper`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#upper).

If you only want the letter to appear once if you have more than one item with that letter (e.g. Apple and Avocado), then you can use [`ifchanged`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged).

```
{% for fruit in fruits %}
    {% ifchanged %}<B>{{ fruit.Name|slice:":1"|upper }}</B><BR>{% endifchanged %}
    <A HREF="{{ fruit.url }}">{{ fruit.Name }}</A><BR>
    {{ fruit.Desc }}<BR>
    {% if not forloop.last %}<BR>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, that does exactly what I wanted. The {% ifchanged %} tag is also a nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in [`capfirst`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#capfirst):

```
{{ fruit.Name|capfirst }}
```